# Builder pattern inside interface. Bad design decision?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I am having trouble evaluating an implementation of the builder pattern I just came up with.

The context is an API library, so I am trying not to expose any implementations in order to have a stable interface while being able to change implementations later.

My thinking is that even though there is a reference to the implementation in the interface's *file*, the interface and the implementation are not actually coupled because

> [In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

The benefit of this design is that clients can call

`Person person = new Person.Builder().age(20).firstName("John")
                .lastName("Doe").build();`

without the need for a dedicated Factory type class.

Am I missing something or is this a valid design decision?

**Person.java**

```
package net.mhi.rd;

public interface Person {

    int getAge();
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();

    public static class Builder {
        int age;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;

        public Builder age(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder firstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder lastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        public Person build() {
            return new PersonImpl(this);
        }
    }    
}
```

**PersonImpl.java**

```
package net.mhi.rd;

class PersonImpl implements Person {

    private final int age;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    PersonImpl(Person.Builder builder) {
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: At the low-level details, you are right static inner class is almost the same as a separate class especially in the perspective of what you are trying to do. However, just keep it outside is a good practice because it is part of the implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main problem is that you've created a circular dependency between Person and PersonImpl... Person shouldn't have any references to implementation classes, but the "new PersonImpl()" call in the builder creates a hard, compile-time dependency on the concrete class.

- I think the fix is to either spin PersonBuilder off into it's own class, or else move PersonBuilder into PersonImpl. It's a little weird declaring a class inside an interface anyway -- I wouldn't say I've never done that, but it seems preferable to keep interfaces simple.
- Passing the Builder as a constructor argument in PersonImpl couples the implementation class really tightly to the builder. You'd be better off keeping a cleaner separation between the builder and the buildee. The builder (obviously) needs to know about PersonImpl, but it would be best if PersonImpl didn't reference the builder.
- Do you anticipate having more than one Person implementation? It's looks like a data class, and I'm not sure you need to extract an interface in the first place.
- And... as a general pattern, if you're going to create a dozen or so classes like this, I think this pattern would become pretty cumbersome -- there's an interface, implementation, and builder for each class. That seems like a lot of extra code for something that may not need distinct interfaces.

Here's the variation to Builder that Josh Block came up with. It's similar in that it uses an inner class to access & set internal values, so that the class becomes effective immutable. I think the main difference with your code is that there's not a separate interface.

http://rwhansen.blogspot.com/2007/07/theres-builder-pattern-that-joshua.html

**TL;DR**:

- the dependencies should go Builder --> Impl --> Interface
- omitting the interface and nesting the Builder inside the *Impl* is a nice way to provide one-time access to the internal impl details, while hiding a circular dependency between builder and impl.

Comment: You are right, the circular dependency is problematic. One could resolve this by mimicking the Builder's `build()` method from the example you provided and setting the PersonImpl's fields to `protected`. But then one would need to keep the package very small to keep the class _effectively immutable_.

Comment: Not sure if the circular dependency is a problem at all. A use case for this design might be that you create a nicer API -- think DSL. For example, the `Map.of()` family of static methods of the `java.util.Map` interface will create concrete maps using other top-level classes that in turn depend on the `Map` interface. Not a problem at all.

Using `Map.of()` to create an empty map is certainly a nicer API than having to resort to something like `MapFactory.create()`.

Answer (score 3):

I very much agree with the opening paragraph and point #3 made by Rob. I am going to elaborate on those because they are in my opinion the most serious design flaws.

You would only really need to create an interface for Person if you are planning to create more than one kind of Person implementation. Otherwise, there really isn't any reason to have it.  Someone might argue that having the Person interface allows you to change the PersonImpl class without affecting the rest of the program. More specifically, the interface prevents any outside parts of the program from communicating directly with PersonImpl, which we know is good for loose coupling.  However,  if there is only ever going to be one Implementation of the Person interface, then that would mean there is no purpose in having it and it would just be extra code. Extra code increases complexity and increased complexity makes the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Under the assumption that you do plan on having more than 1 kind of Person then having an explicit reference to the implementing class in your interface is a mistake because it makes it difficult to extend your interface to new implementations.   Always remember why you're doing what you're doing.  In the case of designing interfaces, we are always trying to achieve greater flexibility and maintainability by ensuring that we rarely have to modify existing code, because modifying existing code usually results in introducing bugs.  In your interface, you have PersonImpl stated in the build() method.  This is a problem because everytime you want to make a new implementation of the Person interface you would need to modify the code in the Interface's class.  In this case, it might not be a problem because there isn't a lot of code, but as the code grows it's very easy for something like this to get lost in the code.

[image]

As a personal note, I recommend complementing code with
UML or a similar graphic representation when communicating
your design ideas.  They are designed specifically for that purpose 
and in almost all cases they have helped me identify design flaws 
in my code which I would not have identified otherwise.

Comment: You made some valid points, but "you only need an interface when you will have more than one implementation" is not general good advice. The Person example here seems artificial, but usually you want to introduce interfaces to decouple architectural layers, no matter how many implementations will exist.

Comment: Why do you want to decouple architectural layers?  So that you can change one without effecting the other.  Would you change an existing one or creating  a new one?   If you change an existing one, you are modifying existing code and breaking the open closed principle.  So you have to create a new one.  So you have a new implementation.  (2 implementations for the same interface) So yes, the number of implementations is directly related to the reasoning for interfaces.  If there is never going to be another implementation, then there is no reason for the abstraction. Avoid speculative design.

Comment: A good example is when you separate your domain logic from the UI. You will create an interface in your domain layer to send data to display to the user in the UI, that will be implemented in the UI layer. You do that to introduce an architectural boundary: UI knows (depends on) the domain, but not vice versa. It does not matter at all _how many_ implementations there will be.

Comment: Another example is when you have persisted entities in a schema-less storage: you will _usually_ have only one implementation, but having an interface allows to refactor it without being forced to migrate all your persisted data at once, in a coordinated way with the model change.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer  After a few years of building,  ( and reading clean architecture by Bob Martin )  I totally get decoupling architectural layers.  I don't know I survived code bases before knowing this.